# nstimer not working properly showing the same data and page controller also not indicate page

Tags: swift

I want to implement the page controller and set the timer for page controller

here I used the label array of object passing the label

but here I got reaping the same values page controller also not moving and when showing the same data in label please help me to solve this issues ...
Thanks in Advance. 
Here is my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
 {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  arrPageTitle = ["In SignUp screen user can able to input the first name, last name, emailid and password.", "After SignUp email verification link has been send to his mail then add basic profile information and sport preferences.", "In Profile setting can view profile, privacy and notifications, friends, account and championships won."];
  self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myPageviewcontroller") as! UIPageViewController
  self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
  let initialContentviewcontroller = self.getViewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) as PageContentViewController
  let viewcontrollers = NSArray(object: initialContentviewcontroller)
  self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
  self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width:self.view.frame.width,height: 350)
  self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
  self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
  self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: (#selector(StartUpPage.advancePage)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

func advancePage () 
 {
   let pvcs = pageViewController.childViewControllers as! [PageContentViewController]
   let itemIndex = pvcs[0].pageIndex
   let firstController = getViewControllerAtIndex(index: itemIndex+1)
   let startingViewControllers = [firstController]
   pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> PageContentViewController
 { // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
            pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
     pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
     return pageContentViewController
 }


func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
 {
   let viewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController
   var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int
   if(index == 0 || index == NSNotFound) { 
       return nil
    }
   index -= 1
   return self.getViewControllerAtIndex(index: index)
 }

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
 {
   let viewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController
   var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int
   if((index == NSNotFound)) {
       return nil
    }
   index += 1
   if(index == arrPageTitle.count) {
      return nil
   }
  return self.getViewControllerAtIndex(index: index)
}

public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
  { 
     return arrPageTitle.count
  }
public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
  {
      return 0
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func advancePage ()
{
    UpdateCounter += 1

    if  UpdateCounter > 2 {
        UpdateCounter = 0

    }
    var nextviewcontroller = self.getViewControllerAtIndex(index: UpdateCounter)
    if (nextviewcontroller .isEqual(nil)) {
        UpdateCounter = 0

        nextviewcontroller = self.getViewControllerAtIndex(index: UpdateCounter)
    }

    let startingViewControllers = [nextviewcontroller]
    pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    pagecontroller.currentPage = UpdateCounter
   pagecontroller.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    pagecontroller.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red

    print(UpdateCounter)



    }
```

try with this code hope will work

Answer (score -1):

So far where i know, UI changes are made in Main thread, so if you use any loop or other method to change this in an interval it will make only the last change in the UI. You could do this with NSRunloop, but it's a little bit dangerous and unpredictable sometimes.

Comment: can u tell me how to do that ..u can post the answer